# Using a custom Drop Down List field to set a value in a grid

Tags: rally

I'm trying to use the Rally 2.1 SDK to set a custom data field (c_wsjf) in a grid.  I have a custom drop down list that I want to check the value of (c_TimeCrticalitySizing).

I created c_TimeCrticalitySizing as a feature card field in my Rally workspace with different string values (such as "No decay"). Every drop down list value will set the custom field to a different integer. When I try to run the app in Rally I get this error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isModel' of undefined(…)"

I'm thinking the drop down list value may not be a string.

How would I check what the type of the drop down list value is?

How could I rewrite this code to correctly check the value of the drop down list so I can set my custom field to different integers?

Here's my code block for the complete app. I'm still trying to hook up a search bar so for now I directly call `_onDataLoaded()` from the `launch()` function.

```
// START OF APP CODE
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
  extend: 'Rally.app.App',
  componentCls: 'app',

  featureStore: undefined,
  featureGrid: undefined,

  items: [      // pre-define the general layout of the app; the skeleton (ie. header, content, footer)
    {
      xtype: 'container', // this container lets us control the layout of the pulldowns; they'll be added below
      itemId: 'widget-container',
      layout: {
              type: 'hbox',           // 'horizontal' layout
              align: 'stretch'
          }
    }
  ],

  // Entry point of the app
  launch: function() {
    var me = this;

    me._onDataLoaded();
  },

  _loadSearchBar: function() {
    console.log('in loadsearchbar');

    var me = this;

    var searchComboBox = Ext.create('Rally.ui.combobox.SearchComboBox', {
      itemId: 'search-combobox',
      storeConfig: {
        model: 'PortfolioItem/Feature'
      },
      listeners: {
        ready: me._onDataLoaded,
        select: me._onDataLoaded,
        scope: me
      }

    });

    // using 'me' here would add the combo box to the app, not the widget container
    this.down('#widget-container').add(searchComboBox); // add the search field to the widget container <this>
  },

  // If adding more filters to the grid later, add them here
  _getFilters: function(searchValue){
    var searchFilter = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Filter', {
      property: 'Search',
      operation: '=',
      value: searchValue
    });

    return searchFilter;
  },

  // Sets values once data from store is retrieved
  _onDataLoaded: function() {
    console.log('in ondataloaded');

    var me = this;

    // look up what the user input was from the search box
    console.log("combobox: ", this.down('#search-combobox'));
    //var typedSearch = this.down('#search-combobox').getRecord().get('_ref');

    // search filter to apply
    //var myFilters = this._getFilters(typedSearch);

    // if the store exists, load new data
    if (me.featureStore) {
      //me.featureStore.setFilter(myFilters);
      me.featureStore.load();
    }
    // if not, create it
    else {
      me.featureStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
        model: 'PortfolioItem/Feature',
        autoLoad: true,
        listeners: {
          load:  me._createGrid,
          scope: me
        },
        fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'TimeCriticality',
        'RROEValue', 'UserBusinessValue', 'JobSize', 'c_TimeCriticalitySizing']
      });
    }

  },

  // create a grid with a custom store
  _createGrid: function(store, data){
    var me = this;

    var records = _.map(data, function(record) {
      //Calculations, etc.
      console.log(record.get('c_TimeCriticalitySizing'));
      var timecritsize = record.get('c_TimeCriticalitySizing');
      //console.log(typeof timecritsize);
      var mystr = "No decay";

      var jobsize = record.get('JobSize');
      var rroe = record.get('RROEValue');
      var userval = record.get('UserBusinessValue');
      var timecrit = record.get('TimeCriticality');

      // Check that demoniator is not 0
      if ( record.get('JobSize') > 0){
        if (timecritsize === mystr){
          var priorityScore = (timecrit + userval + rroe) / jobsize;

          return Ext.apply({
            c_wsjf: Math.round(priorityScore * 10) / 10
          }, record.getData());
        }

      }
      else{
        return Ext.apply({
          c_wsjf: 0
        }, record.getData());
      }
    });

    // Add the grid
    me.add({
      xtype: 'rallygrid',
      showPagingToolbar: true,
      showRowActionsColumn: true,
      enableEditing: true,
      store: Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
        data: records
      }),

      // Configure each column
      columnCfgs: [
        {
          xtype: 'templatecolumn',
          text: 'ID',
          dataIndex: 'FormattedID',
          width: 100,
          tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
        },
        {
          text: 'WSJF Score',
          dataIndex: 'c_wsjf',
          width: 150
        },
        {
          text: 'Name',
          dataIndex: 'Name',
          flex: 1,
          width: 100
        }
      ]
    });
  }

});
// END OF APP CODE
```

The app works great until I add the `if (timecritsize === mystr)` conditional.
I also use console.log() to check that I've set all values for timecritsize to "No decay"

Comment: I used `typeof` on timecritsize and it returned string so now I'm pretty sure my syntax is just wrong.

Comment: That error is usually thrown from a store that is having trouble figuring out what its model or proxy is.  Did you figure out your error?  Can you post more of your code so we have more context around what you're trying to do?

Comment: Still haven't gotten it. That `if (timecritsize === mystr)` conditional seems to cause the break though. Are there any good books/references for debugging in the Ext framework that Rally devs/engineers use?

Comment: you know how to use the debugger; keyword and/or how to set code breakpoints in your browser's dev tools right?

Comment: other than that, the sdk docs are the main resource: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide